# Not satisfied: inferred type T? is not subtype of Any

Tags: generics, kotlin, bounds, kotlin-android-extensions

To map the result I have implemented sealed generic class :

```
public sealed class ResultMapper<out T : Any> {
    public class Ok<out T : Any>(public val value: T,
                            override val response: Response) : Result<T>(), ResponseResult {
        override fun toString(): String = "Result.Ok{value=$value, response=$response}"
    }
}

   public interface ResponseResult {
     val response: Response
   }
```

Now I suppose to this class should work as expected below behaviour:

```
 ResultMapper.Ok(body,raw)

private class Body<T>() {
  onResponse(response: Response, raw: Raw) {
   ResultMapper.Ok(response.body(),response.raw()) --> It returned an exception
  }
}
```

> Constructor Ok is not satisfied: inferred type T? is not subtype of
>   **Any**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The class `Body` has a generic type parameter `T` without any bounds, i.e. it’s like defining `T: Any?` whereas `Ok`’s type parameter is confined to be `T: Any`. You should adjust `Body` to not allow nullable types either:

```
class Body<T: Any>
```

Alternatively, remove the upper bound in the other classes.

Comment: I am just wondering to remove Any from  ResultMapper class like : `ResultMapper <out T>` cause many inbuilt class not allow with Any explicit type. Do you think this one is ok ?

Comment: That’s an alternative, sure you can do it when nullable types are okay for your use case